# Iterate an array with index in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to iterate an array with an index in Swift 3 but keep getting

> Expression type '[Int]' is ambiguous without more context

this is reproducible with the following example in a playground:

```
var a = [Int]()
a.append(1)
a.append(2)
// Gives above error
for (index, value) in a {
  print("\(index): \(value)")
}
```

I'm not sure what context it is asking for.

Comment: Saying `in a` gives you _one_ value (i.e. 1, or 2), not a _tuple_ with both an index and a value.

Comment: Can anyone help me understand why this question received a downvote? How can I improve it?

Comment: It's so careless. `for (index,value) in a`, when `a` is an array, is just silly talk.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You forgot to call `a.enumerated()`, which is what gives you the `(index, value)` tuples. `for value in a` is what gives you each element *without* the index.

Answer (score 4):

Correct Code:

```
var a = [Int]()
a.append(1)
a.append(2)
// Gives above error
for (index, value) in a.enumerated() {
    print("\(index): \(value)")
}
```